# python-telegram-bot http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response after executed postponed job_queue.run_once job

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I wrote a python-telegram-bot in order to get rid of timers and clocks without records of launch.
But unfortunately on testing I ran into strange problem I couldn't understand - a HTTPError (`http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response`) happens every time when a job in job_queue is executing after selected 15-minute delay.
I tried to google this problem and added some keyword arguments `timeout=3600` in the code but this change has no influence on bot's perfomance.
Could anyone clarify what things I don't understand?
Much obliged in advance.

here is my code consisting of two files:

`test_bot.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import pytz
import telegram_bot_config as t

from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, ParseMode
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler, Defaults
import datetime as dt

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def make_kb():
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Send message in 15 minutes", callback_data=t.BUTTON_LABEL1)],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Send message in 4 hours", callback_data=t.BUTTON_LABEL2)],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    return reply_markup


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
    reply_markup = make_kb()
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def alarm(context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send the alarm message."""
    job = context.job
    dt_now = dt.datetime.now()
    dt_now_str = dt.datetime.strftime(dt_now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    delta_dt = (dt_now - dt.datetime.strptime(job.context["dt_start"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elapsed = dt.timedelta(delta_dt.total_seconds())
    answer = '{0} were elapsed!*'.format(elapsed)
    text_message = "You had pressed the button at *{0}*.\nAfter waiting I sent it at *{1}*".format(
        job.context["dt_start"],
        dt_now_str)
    context.bot.send_message(job.context["chat_id"], text=answer, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
    context.bot.send_message(job.context["chat_id"], text=text_message, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)


def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    data = query.data
    query.message.reply_text("You selected *" + data + "* option!", parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)

    dt_start = dt.datetime.now()
    chat_id = query.message.chat_id
    payload = {"chat_id": chat_id, "dt_start": dt.datetime.strftime(dt_start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}

    if data == '15m':
        context.job_queue.run_once(alarm, t.DURATION_15M, context=payload, name=str(chat_id))
    if data == '4h':
        context.job_queue.run_once(alarm, t.DURATION_4H, context=payload, name=str(chat_id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Run bot."""
    defaults = Defaults(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'),)

    updater = Updater(t.TOKEN, request_kwargs={'read_timeout': 4*3600, 'connect_timeout': 4*3600})

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling(timeout=4*3600)

    updater.idle()
```

`telegram_bot_config.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
TOKEN = "YOUR TOKEN HERE!"

DURATION_15M = 60*15
DURATION_4H = 60*60*4

BUTTON_LABEL1 = "15m"
BUTTON_LABEL2 = "4h"
```

An error which occurs every time after 15-minute waiting of message:

```
C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/test/Dropbox/Development/TelegramTimerBot/test4.py
2021-07-01 22:43:37,315 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler started
2021-07-01 22:43:43,133 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Added job "1234567" to job store "default"
2021-07-01 22:58:43,098 - apscheduler.executors.default - INFO - Running job "1234567 (trigger: date[2021-07-01 19:58:43 UTC], next run at: 2021-07-01 19:58:43 UTC)" (scheduled at 2021-07-01 19:58:43.092836+00:00)
2021-07-01 22:58:43,099 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Removed job 8ed316fd7340464b948d0f41bce318de
2021-07-01 22:58:43,105 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 617, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 402, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 275, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 259, in _request_wrapper
    resp = self._con_pool.request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\request.py", line 70, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\request.py", line 148, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 244, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 666, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 347, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 617, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 402, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 275, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/test/Dropbox/Development/TelegramTimerBot/test4.py", line 52, in alarm
    context.bot.send_message(job.context["chat_id"], text=text_message, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 129, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 507, in send_message
    api_kwargs=api_kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\extbot.py", line 206, in _message
    api_kwargs=api_kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 331, in _message
    result = self._post(endpoint, data, timeout=timeout, api_kwargs=api_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 295, in _post
    f'{self.base_url}/{endpoint}', data=data, timeout=effective_timeout
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 361, in post
    **urlopen_kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\test\Dropbox\Development\TelegramTimerBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 265, in _request_wrapper
    raise NetworkError(f'urllib3 HTTPError {error}') from error
telegram.error.NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Answer (score 1):

IISC `RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')` means that Telegram closed the connection, i.e. it's not an issue on your/ptbs side. What startles me a bit is that - if I understood correctly -

- this happens consistently
- this doesn't happen for any other request to the API
- it happens only for the second `send_message` request in `alarm`, but not for the first one

Can you confirm all of the above? Can you try if the same problem occurs when you change the interval or even run the code inside `alarm` directly (instead of scheduling a job)?

I suggest to also have a look at ptbs wiki page on [network errors](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Handling-network-errors).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

---

### Edit

I tried to reproduce, but did not get any exception. I'm on the latest version of PTB (actually, on `master` branch …) and use py3.7 under Windows. Also I compressed your example a bit, so for completeness sake here is the mwe I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
import datetime as dt

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def alarm(context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send the alarm message."""
    job = context.job
    dt_now = dt.datetime.now()
    dt_now_str = dt.datetime.strftime(dt_now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    delta_dt = (dt_now - dt.datetime.strptime(job.context["dt_start"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elapsed = dt.timedelta(seconds=delta_dt.total_seconds())
    answer = '{0} were elapsed!*'.format(elapsed)
    text_message = f'You had pressed the button at *{job.context["dt_start"]}*.\nAfter waiting I ' \
                   f'sent it at *{dt_now_str}* '
    context.bot.send_message(job.context["chat_id"], text=answer)
    context.bot.send_message(job.context["chat_id"], text=text_message)


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    offset = 60*15
    update.effective_message.reply_text(f'will run in {offset} seconds')

    dt_start = dt.datetime.now()
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    payload = {"chat_id": chat_id, "dt_start": dt.datetime.strftime(dt_start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}

    job = context.job_queue.run_once(alarm, offset, context=payload, name=str(chat_id))
    job.run(context.dispatcher)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Run bot."""
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Comment: 1) *this happens consistently* 
Yes, if I pass a 15-minute delay to a *job_queue.run_once* function. Any time less then 15*60 seconds works well (I tested it
https://i.imgur.com/KKBqESj.png)

2) *this doesn't happen for any other request to the API*
Couldn't verify it, unfortunately - I just started learning the API

3) *it happens only for the second send_message request in alarm, but not for the first one* It happens before first sending of message. And today I got message `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Comment: any ideas or hints? Should I register a ticket at ptb-tracker?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I missed the notification. I'll have to try to reproduce.

Comment: may i know of your code is workinf now ? I got the aame issue.